# Openshift 3: Where are the log files and how to manage them?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I have a Openshift 3 starter app (python).  Using the web console I can see my logs.  Where is the actual file? After a while the file will be getting big and will needed to be deleted I assume.

On Openshift 2 there was a "rhc tidy" command to clean the log files out.  Is there something similar for Openshift 3? Is there a way to do this automatically? On Openshift 2 I was able to set up a cron job to do this monthly however Openshift 3 Starter does not support cron jobs.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in OpenShift 3 is to `stdout`, it's the standard method of logging for Docker containers. So no files to worry about keeping tidy.